# Create event with unique recurring rule in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

I need to create a recurring event in Google Calendar that happens on the first Friday after (but not including) the 15th of each month.

I tried to use the "every third Friday" rule that is built in, but that creates at least three events over the next two years that are not correct (January 2016 being the first month that is not right). I also tried to use the `RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=FR;BYMONTHDAY=16,17,18,19,20,21,22;BYSETPOS=1` notation, but Google Calendar does not seem to recognise the event at all when I try to import it.

Even a "quick add" string that will produce these results would be great.

For reference, I get the first Friday of each pay period off, our pay periods are the 1st through 15th and 16th through end of month. I need to add these to my calendar for my manager to see.

Comment: Unfortunately, Google Calendar isn't sophisticated enough to have such a recurring rule. However, it does import ical files, so if you could find something else that can do that rule and export to an ical file, you can import it into Google Calendar.

Comment: I understand that Google Calendar is not able to natively create such a rule, I do not have access to a program at this time that can create such a rule, so I need to be able to either create the ical file manually or create a "quick add" string that GCal will parse into this rule.